# Chart.js Bar Chart with a switch/radio button to group data / Troubleshooting bar color

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

My main goal is to create a switch/radio button to group data (instead of having filters at the top). Look at screenshots for reference please:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to group data and turn the filter buttons into a switch?

If not possible, my plan B is to show all the data at once, and keep filter at the top.
Here is the code and jsfiddle link:

```
<!-- Charts library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["option 1", "option 2"],

            datasets: [
        {
        label: 'yes',
        data: [714,233],
        backgroundColor: '#004831',
        },
        {
        label: 'no',
        data: [800, 451],
        backgroundColor: '#76B900'
        }
            ]},

        options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
            }
            }]
        }
        }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fariadesign/kL810rnq/9/

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works about like this ...

```js
var chart = null;

var chartData = {
  labels: ['Question 1', 'Question 2'],
  datasets: [
    {label: 'yes', backgroundColor: '#004831', data: [714, 233]},
    {label: 'no', backgroundColor: '#76B900', data: [800, 451]}
  ]
};

var chartOptions = {
  tooltips: {mode: 'index', intersect: true},
  legend: {display: false},
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {beginAtZero: true},
      stacked: true
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {beginAtZero: true},
      stacked: false
    }]
  }
};

$(function() {

  chart = new Chart($('#chart'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions
  });
  
  $("input#toggle[type='checkbox']").click(function (event) {
    var isStacked = false;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      isStacked = true;
    } else {
      isStacked = false;
    }
    
    chart.options.scales = {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: isStacked }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: isStacked }]
    };
    chart.update();
  });
  
});
```

```css
canvas {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
}
.toggle {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 55px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
.toggle-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.toggle-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px; padding: 0; line-height: 20px;
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #9E9E9E;
}
.toggle-label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block; width: 30px; margin: -5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 31px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0px #757575;
}
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
    background-color: #42A5F5;
}
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label, .toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label:before {
   border-color: #42A5F5;
}
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label .toggle-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label:before {
    right: 0px; 
    background-color: #2196F3; 
    box-shadow: 3px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" class="toggle-checkbox"/>
    <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<canvas id="chart" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```

here's the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: Thank you! But why is just showing one bar? I saw you input the number for two bars in each instance..

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added another screenshot. No, I meant have two bars for each instance (yes and no).

Comment: @Marcio updated the script meanwhile; there problem is just, that there are four values to plot, while your screenshots only display two values at a time.

Comment: Thank you! Well, my code is was just a "plan b", because I thought "plan a" (screenshots) was not possible. I need two values to plot (not four) but they change from "yes" and "no". So: option 1 = 714 if yes / 800 if no ... and option 2 = 233 is yes /  451 if no. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Marcio updated that accordingly, as if they were polling results. `chart.js` basically takes arrays of equal length as input data-sets and then plots the values by their index; it's not alike other charting libraries, where one can simply define series. and in an IDE this might be easier to adjust, than in this snippet editor, without the least debugger.

Comment: it is not really working properly. Each bar has two color/values and when the switch is changed a couple of time, it becomes 4 bars again. Any other ideas? Or recommendation to go away from chart.js ??

Comment: @Marcio maybe just provide two arrays with one value each ...this is meant as an example and I'm not here to do your work, without the least compensation. can in best case provide a similar `NV3D` example: https://nvd3.syslogic.io/#MultiBarChart